# Ubuntu 20.04.1 frozen when booting

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.16 in Windows 10
While booting up the Screen hangs on the Ubuntu logo. I haven't changed anything but there was a recent Windows security update for the host computer. If that is an issue I can roll this back however I want to cross out any other reasons first.

The log file ends with the following:

00:00:42.261482 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:42.275300 NAT: IPv6 not supported

While it is booting I get the Error messages

- Failed to start Modem Manager
- Failed to start Hostname Service
- Failed to start Login Service

Image below for more information
[Login process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KSdf.jpg)

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Since the latest Ubuntu runs on my VirtualBox on a linux host I'd suggest you'd  downgrade to 6.1.14 -Thats the version I'm running - I've had regressions once in a while with new versions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I ended up just creating a new partition, opening the original disk image with 7 Zip and grabbing the documents I needed and starting again.